# Printing out sum of each pair of vector elements - C++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to printing out sum of each pair of adjacent elements in a vector. But the code shown below is not giving me the correct result. Anyone can help me with this?

int main()
{

```
vector <int> num(10);
vector <int> res(5);
int get = 0;
int range = 0;

for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
    cin >> get;
    num.push_back(get);
}

while (range != num.size()) {
    int c = 0;
    int c1 = c + 1;
    res.push_back(num[c] + num[c1]);
    if (c == 0)
        c = 1;
    c *= 2;
    ++range;

}
cout << res[7];

for (int u = 0; u != res.size(); ++u) {
    cout << res[u] << " ";
}

return 0;
```

}

**Update: -**

I've changed this code as you mentioned in the comment section, but when I compile it showing me a debug error.

I able to read 1-10 integers into the 'num' vector. But when I hit enter after read all the integers into the vector, this debug error happens.

```
int main()
{

    vector <int> num;
    vector <int> res;

    int get = 0;
    int range = 0;
    int c = 0, c1 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i) {
        cin >> get;
        num.push_back(get);
    }

    while (range != num.size()) {
        c1 = c + 1;
        res.push_back(num[c] + num[c1]);
        if (c == 0)
            c = 1;
        c *= 2;
        ++range;

    }

    for (int u = 0; u != res.size(); ++u) {
        cout << res[u] << " ";
    }

    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it step by step?

Comment: c seems to be always 0, c1 always 1, since you declare them within the while-loop.

Comment: You initialize `c` and `c1` at every iteration in the `while()` loop. Is that intended? Best you run your program in a debugger and step through line by line.

Comment: Your vectors already contain 10 and 5 elements, respectively. These are all zero, and using `push_back` adds elements after those zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you doing this:

```
if (c == 0)
    c = 1;
c *= 2;
```

What it does on first iteration is that c = 1 then it multiplies it by 2, so c=2 for 2nd iteration and c1 becomes 3.
So first your code will do num[0] + num[1] and in next iteration it will do num[2] + num[3] and third will do num[4] + num[5] and fourth will do num[8]+num[9] and so on.

I can see two approaches to this:

1) If you want to do adjacent addition like 0+1, 1+2, 2+3 then simply do c++ instead of those three lines of code.
2) If you want to do adjacent addition like 0+1, 2+3, 4+5 you can simply do c = c1+1 instead of those three lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the loop increment.
Try this

```
while (range < num.size()) 
{
        int c = 0;
        int c1 = c + 1;
        res.push_back(num[c] + num[c1]);
        c += 2;
        ++range;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change your code to make it compile and to make it reproducible (a good MCVE doesn't require user input):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> num =
        { 0, 0,
          5, 10,
          -5, 5,
          3, -20};

    std::vector<int> res;
    unsigned int range = 0;
    int c = 0, c1 = 0;

    while (range != num.size()) {
        c1 = c + 1;
        res.push_back(num[c] + num[c1]);
        if (c == 0)
            c = 1;
        c *= 2;
        ++range;
    }

    for (unsigned int u = 0; u != res.size(); ++u) {
        std::cout << res[u] << " ";
    }
}
```

Your problem is that you are multiplying `c` by two, instead of adding two, each iteration.

Here's a more idiomatic version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> num
        = { 0, 0,
            5, 10,
            -5, 5,
            3, -20, };

    std::vector<int> res;

    const auto last = num.end();
    for (auto it = num.begin();  it != last;  ) {
        auto v = *it++;
        res.push_back(v + (it == last ? 0 : *it++));
    }

    for (auto v: res)
        std::cout << v << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If this is homework, I suggest you make sure you understand it fully before you hand it in.

Answer (score 0):

One solution using STL iterators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v
    { 0, 0,
      5, 10,
      -5, 5,
      3, -20};
    for(auto& r : v) std::cout << r << "\t"; std::cout << std::endl; // print
    //Calculate now the adjacent sum (sum of consecutive elements)
    std::adjacent_difference(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), [](const int x, const int y) { return x+y; });//here, set execution policy to parallel if wanted
    v.erase(v.begin()); // pop_front
    // print now every second element. Change i+=2 to i++ if you want every consecutive sum
    for(size_t i = 0; i<v.size(); i+=2) std::cout << v[i] << "\t"; std::cout << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

which results in:

```
0       0       5       10      -5      5       3       -20
0       15      0       -17
```

Answer (score -2):

The biggest issue I see here, in addition to what was mentioned in the comments, is that you're only incrementing **range** by 1 instead of 2.  This causes your code to overshoot the end of the vector, which means your sum is being corrupted by garbage data.

Comment: that alone wont fix anything. Btw he is not using garbage data, the only elements he ever accesses are `num[0]` and `num[1]`

Comment: The code is repeatedly adding `num[0]` and `num[1]`, which are valid (they're 0).

Comment: @molbdnilo, no, `c` goes from 0 to 1, then it's being *multiplied* (for some reason) by two each iteration, so it will step through the binary powers: 0, 2, 4, 8, ....

Comment: @TobySpeight The updated code does that, but the original code has `int c = 0;` inside the loop.